# Irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_2$

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

> Let $t$ a transcendental element on $\mathbb{F}_2$. Prove that $f(x)=x^3-t^3$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_2(t^3)[x]$.

If $f$ is reducible, then we have a solution of $x^3-t^3$, we can call it $\alpha$. So $\alpha \in \mathbb{F}_2(t^3)$ and then $\mathbb{F}_2(t^3)= \mathbb{F}_2(\alpha) $, but after this? How can I conclude the proof to get the desired outcome?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I don't even see how you get "If $f$ is reducible, then [...]".  The only route I see for that statement is first proving $x^2 + tx + t^2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_2(t)[x]$, but have you shown that?

Comment: Oh yes, I am wrong. But in any case I don’t know how to use the fact that $t$ is transcendental

Comment: If $a$ is not a cube in the field $F$ then $x^3-a$ is irreducible in $F[x]$. That should do it.  More generally, any cubic ( or quadratic)  without roots is irreducible.

Comment: Yes, but why I don’t have a root of $x^3 - t^3$ in $\mathbb{F}_2(t^3)$ ?

Comment: Just to elaborate on @orangeskid answer (+1), show you cannot have $t^{3} = f(t^{3})^{3}/g(t^{3})^{3}$.for polynomials $f, g$, with $g \ne 0$.

Comment: Isn't $t^3$ prime in $\mathbb{F}_2[t^3]$? So one can use Eisenstein etc.

Comment: $t^3$ or any other non-constant fraction $r(t)$ from $K[t]$ is not algebraic over $K$. Hence, if we have  $P(r(t)) = 0$ in $K[t]$, then $P\equiv 0$. So if we had $t^3 =( f(t^3)/g(t^3))^3$, then $t = (f(t)/g(t))^3$   (here of course $3$ appears in two places and it does confuse the things a bit).